# USB-C male to 2 female inside

Tags: usb, usb-c

I want a USB-C male connector to use my [Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(standard)) tag charger and also have one USB port free to use with the regular charger without unplugging the Qi tag.

I can't find a good splitter for USB-C. I found one for USB-C audio and USB-C charging and I remember some kind of connectors that have inside a female and at the same time they were male. I could solder the Qi tag to this splitter and it may be ok

Comment: Qi is a standard for wireless loading of phones. But what is a "Qi tag charger"? Google does not know the terminology.

Comment: Just a splitter won't do what you want. You need a USB-C hub designed for this. Please click [edit] and provide more information on this 'tag charger'.